# How to run db migration script in a kubernetes pod from bash?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to run database migration scripts in Ubuntu pod automatically.

How I am doing this manually:

```sh
$ kubectl run -i --tty ubuntu --image=ubuntu:focal -- bash
$ apt install -y postgresql-client
$ psql "hostaddr=addr port=5432 user=username password=pass dbname=dbname"

COPY persons(first_name, last_name, dob, email)
FROM './persons.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;

$ exit
```

I would like to create a bash script for this purposes to run locally. Could you please advise how to script it? First command connects to a remote bash session, and I am not able to execute other commands. Definitely doing something wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you bake this all into a self-contained image, push it to a registry, and then run it as a Job?  Or, does your application contain some sort of full-featured database migration system already, so you can create a Job with your application image and an alternate command to launch the migration?

Comment: Thanks David, it is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Use here documents.

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl run -i --tty ubuntu --image=ubuntu:focal -- bash <<EOF
apt install -y postgresql-client
psql "hostaddr=addr port=5432 user=username password=pass dbname=dbname" <<EOF2

COPY persons(first_name, last_name, dob, email)
FROM './persons.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;

EOF2
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have a command that is supposed to be run to execute some SQL query on a postgresql server in a Kubernetes cluster:

```
 export pgcmd="PGPASSWORD=pass1234 psql -U username -d mydatabase -h addr -p port -c \"COPY persons(first_name, last_name, dob, email) FROM './persons.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;\" "
```

or by using [URL syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING)

```
 export pgcmd="psql postgresql://username:pass@addr:5432/mydatabase -c \"COPY persons(first_name, last_name, dob, email) FROM './persons.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;\" "
```

Actually, it's more convenient to use official postgres docker image instead of installing postgresql client on Ubuntu image:
(if I use the same image as used to spin up the posgresql server, I can save some time on pulling image from the repository)

```
kubectl run -it --rm pgclient --image=postgres -- $pgcmd
```

Alternatively you can run the command using posgresql pod itself

```
kubectl exec -it posgresql-server-pod-name -- $pgcmd
```

or proxy connection to the postgresql server and execute the command there

```
kubectl port-forward posgresql-server-pod-name 8888:5432 &
#or we can use parent object to connect 
#kubectl port-forward deployment/posgresql-server-deploy-name 8888:5432 &

# save ID of the background process
proxyid=$!

# run postgres command locally
$pgcmd

# switch off port forwarding and cleanup environment variables
unset PGPASSWORD
kill $proxyid && unset proxyid
```